# Encoding of filenames containing non-latin characters while extracting from .tar.gz packed by Ant tar task

Tags: linux, ant, encoding, tar

I'm building a tar.gz archive using Ant:

```
<tar destfile="${linux86.zip.file}" compression="gzip" longfile="gnu">
    <tarfileset dir="${work.dir}/data" dirmode="755" filemode="755"  
                prefix="${app.folder}/data"/>
</tar>
```

Archive is built on Windows. After being extracted on Ubuntu 12 files with names containing non-latin (for example, cyrillic) characters have broken names.

Is there any way to fix or work around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some interesting information in Ant's developer mailing list ([30 Jun 2009](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-dev/200906.mbox/%3C1221280166.20090630200129%40yandex.ru%3E), [01 Jul 2009](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-dev/200907.mbox/%3Cy1ur5x091q8.fsf%40v30161.1blu.de%3E)) and in ASF Bugzilla ([36851](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36851), [53811](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53811)). The problem is old and well-known, it has not been fixed mainly for ideological reasons because not all untar implementations support that.

Patch mentioned in Bugzilla issue has been applied in revision [1350857](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1350857). There is a constructor with name of encoding for entry name in tar:

```
public TarOutputStream(OutputStream os, String encoding) { ... }
```

But it is never used in Tar task though. So I made an encoding attribute in Tar task, rebuilt Ant from modified sources and used UTF-8 as encoding of entry names.

Extraction tested under Ubuntu 11/12 and Mandriva.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. I wanted to post some more info, but you were faster. Anyway, here is another bug entry related to your issue. If I read it correctly, there may be kind of encoding support in ant 1.9, triggered by `longfile="posix"`. [Bug 53921](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53921).

Answer (score 1):

No. Tar archives support only ascii filenames. See this question: [Creating tar archive with national characters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491725/creating-tar-archive-with-national-characters-in-java). I think you need another format or tool, with more modern design.

Note that [zip task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) has `encoding` attribute, maybe this format will work?

Comment: We use tar/gzip to preserve permissons. Unfortunately I can't use zip as you suggested.

Comment: I see. If that's worth it, you may analyze the contents of a tar created on Ubuntu. Then write a program to edit the Windows tar and convert the filenames to a format proper for Ubuntu. Or develop custom untar task doing the filename conversions. Tar format document is linked from the answer I linked above.

Comment: Someone did a similar thing in Python: http://superuser.com/questions/60379/create-a-zip-tgz-in-linux-such-that-windows-han-proper-filenames#190786

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution [there](https://superuser.com/questions/60379/how-can-i-create-a-zip-tgz-in-linux-such-that-windows-has-proper-filenames#190786), HUGE thanks to Jarekczek, but I didn't get decoded names right. I fixed the script as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Huge thanks to https://superuser.com/questions/60379/how-can-i-create-a-zip-tgz-in-linux-such-that-windows-has-proper-filenames#190786
# and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456560/encoding-of-filenames-containing-non-latin-characters-while-extracting-from-tar
import tarfile
import codecs
import sys

def recover(name):
    return codecs.decode(name, 'cp1251')

for tar_filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    tar = tarfile.open(name=tar_filename, mode='r', bufsize=16*1024)
    updated = []
    for m in tar.getmembers():
        m.name = recover(m.name)
        updated.append(m)
    tar.extractall(members=updated)
    tar.close()
```

What I did is to decode names from Windows to utf using Python's standart library codecs and command line interface to feed it the name(s) of archives.