# Saving the file name when using tar

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create archive file. the folder contains files with Russian names. these names are not saved correctly in the archive. Is there a way to save these names in Russian using "tar" or some other command?

```
myDate=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
myTime=$(date +"%H%M%S")

cd /data/folder1
tar -czvf /data/folder2/folder1_$myDate'_'$myTime.tar.gz *
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: You need to double-quote your variables like `tar -czvf "/data/folder2/folder1_${myDate}_${myTime}.tar.gz" *`

Comment: Add output of `locale` to your question (no comment).

Comment: The quotes are not relevant.  If the Russian names are not stored correctly, then there would appear to be a problem with inconsistent use of character sets.  We can't answer that here without a lot more information.   Also, because SO is about programming, this might better be asked on Unix+Linux.

Comment: See also: [Encoding of filenames containing non-latin characters while extracting from .tar.gz packed by Ant tar task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22830245/7939871)

Comment: Irrelevant to the root problem, but the first two lines could be consolidated as `myDateAndTime=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)` and used `tar -czvf /data/folder2/folder1_$myDateAndTime.tar.gz *`.